# How can I set value to zero when an array find repeated value?

Tags: python, arrays, list

This is my current array:

```
arr=np.array([0,  50,  50, 50, 150, 150, 150,150])
```

I wonder how to control array when the second repeated number has found, then should be zero like this:

```
 arr=np.array([0,  50,  0, 0, 150, 0, 0, 0])
```

Then, I would like to keep an column index that value more than 0

```
arr2=np.array([ 1, 4])
```

Would you have any idea to suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using NumPy's indexing and boolean masking.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150])

duplicate_indices = np.where(arr[1:] == arr[:-1])[0] + 1

arr[duplicate_indices] = 0

non_zero_indices = np.where(arr > 0)[0]

print("Modified array:", arr)
print("Indices with non-zero values:", non_zero_indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I like the answer with `np.where`, I want to add a version without using `numpy`. The idea is to iterate though the array backwards and change the element on the right hand if it equals to the current element.

```py
def replace_duplicates(lst, replace_val=0):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst
    
    for i in range(len(lst) - 2, -1, -1):
        if lst[i] == lst[i + 1]:
            lst[i + 1] = replace_val
        
    return lst


lst = np.array([0, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150])
replace_duplicates(lst)
```

Output:

```
array([  0,  50,   0,   0, 150,   0,   0,   0])
```